# Grace Dependency Injection breaks project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

Я начал писать проект с нуля, поэтому я хотел реализовать DependencyInjection. Выбрал Grace, потому что он уже реализован на старом проекте, его писал не я, так что теперь я столкнулся с сложностями. Пытался написать DependencyInjection в Autofac, но меня не устраивает прописка зависимостей в ConfigureServices или в main. Поэтому я решил остановиться на Grace.

Project setting: ASP.NET Core Web Application, Core 2.2, Grace 7.0.1

## DependencyInjection

```
public class GraceContainer : IContainer
    {
        private DependencyInjectionContainer _container;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        internal GraceContainer(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _container = ConfigureContainer(configuration);
        }

        private static DependencyInjectionContainer ConfigureContainer(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var container = new DependencyInjectionContainer();
            ConfigureContainer(container, configuration);
            return container;
        }

        public static void ConfigureContainer(IInjectionScope scope, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            scope.Configure(c => c.ExportInstance(configuration).As<IConfiguration>());

            scope.Configure(c => c.Export<ProjectRepository>().As<IProjectRepository>());
            scope.Configure(c => c.Export<ProjectService>().As<IProjectService>());

            // possible fix for https://github.com/ipjohnson/Grace/issues/116
            scope.Configure(c =>
                c.ExcludeTypeFromAutoRegistration("Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.RegistryPolicyResolver"));
        }

        public T Get<T>()
        {
            return _container.Locate<T>();
        }

        public void Replace<I, T>()
        {
            _container.Dispose();
            _container = ConfigureContainer(_configuration);
            _container.Configure(c => c.Export<T>().As<I>());
        }

        public void Replace<T>(T instance)
        {
            _container.Dispose();
            _container = ConfigureContainer(_configuration);
            _container.Configure(c => c.ExportInstance(instance).As<T>());
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.Locate(serviceType);
        }
    }
```

## Startup

```
public void ConfigureContainer(IInjectionScope scope)
        {
            GraceContainer.ConfigureContainer(scope, Configuration);
            scope.SetupMvc();
        }
```

## Program

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseGrace()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

## Controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/auth")]
    public class ServiceController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProjectRepository _projectRepository;
        private readonly IProjectService _projectService;

        public ServiceController(IProjectRepository projectRepository, IProjectService projectService)
        {
            _projectRepository = projectRepository;
            _projectService = projectService;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Repository List
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet("api/repository_from_git_hub")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetGitHubRepositories(string login, DateTime startDate = new DateTime()) =>
            new OkObjectResult(await _projectService.ProjectPages(login, startDate));
    }
```

И в итоге что я получил после запуска
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста, кто знает как решить эту проблему, дебаг мнне ничего не показал.

P.S. Swagger работает з пустыми ендпойнтами

Comment: Извините, но здесь общаются на русском языке. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос или опубликуйте его на english SO.

Comment: Интересно, чем вам не угодил родной встроенный контейнер, который есть в ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Вы про Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?

Comment: Да, про него. В классе `Startup` есть метод `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` вот в нем и регистрируете, например `services.AddTransient<IPeopleService, PeopleService>();`.

Comment: Такс, я только решил создать простой GetSomeText и проверить рабоатет хотя бы он, и он работает, проблема совсем не в Grace, что-то ломает свагер на уровне контролера

Comment: Все, проблема решена, ломало свагер, то что по дефолту я присваевал DateTime startDate = new DateTime, это его и ломало

Answer (score 0):

Ломает Сваггер не Grace, а то что в контроллере по дефолту присваювается DateTime startDate = new DateTime()

```
[HttpGet("api/repository_from_git_hub")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetGitHubRepositories(string login, DateTime startDate) =>
            new OkObjectResult(await _projectService.ProjectPages(login, startDate));
```